# Jackson versions picked with spark 2.2.0

Tags: java, apache-spark, jackson

We recently upgraded spark to `2.2.0` in our application and this brings in `Jackson 2.6.5` jars in the runtime.

But we have other services that need `Jackson 2.8.6`(due to `Elastic 5.5.0`) the service has a manifest which refers to `Jackson 2.8.6` from the application's lib folder.

So there are two versions of Jackson jars loaded in the runtime and spark is picking a wrong one (`2.8.6` from lib folder instead of `2.6.5` from its own jars folder)

On windows the version picked is the right one although both versions are still loaded in the runtime.

But it fails on Linux.

How do we resolve this?

Comment: I believe this is better suited to our sister site, Serverfault.

Comment: @karlphillip Why? It's about Java classpath resolution, not professional networking

Comment: `SPARK_HOME` shouldn't be combined with Elasticsearch, so unless you are using the Elastic connector for Spark, I think you should double check that Spark 2 support Elastic 5.5.0

Comment: @cricket_007 My bad, you are right. Since this is a topic related to development environments is probably better suited for this site.